# É possivel atribuir o valor de uma variável JavaScript, para uma em ASP

Tags: javascript, asp

Gostaria de saber se é possível atribuir uma variável em *JavaScript* para *ASP*?

***Exemplo:***

```
Dim ASP
var JS;

ASP = 1
JS = 2;

ASP = JS
```

---

```
Response.Write ASP ' saida deveria ser 2 e
```

Comment: Depende de como está usando o JavaScript pois existe o JavaScript server-side, mas acho que não seja o seu caso.

Para enviar um dado em JavaScript para um script server-side, utilize xmlhttp (ajax) ou http padrão..

Comment: ok vou pesquisar sobre, obrigado

Comment: Uma questão idêntica, porém com PHP...  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%C3%A1vel-php-a-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-javascript/25275

Answer (score 5):

JavaScript é processado pelo Browser e o ASP é processado no servidor antes de entregar para o usuário.

Nessas condições, a resposta é Não, não é possível.

Você teria que utilizar um Javascript para enviar a informação por POST ou GET a uma página ASP, e assim você captura o valor pelo `request` e armazena na variável ASP.

O Inverso (Armazenar valor de uma variável ASP em uma variável JS) é possível fazendo apenas:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var x = <%=y%>;
</script>
```

Comment: Tome bastante cuidado se você quiser passar uma string do ASP para o JS dessa forma. É muito escrever o programa de uma forma que é vulnerável a ataques de injeção de código (XSS)

Comment: @hugomg Achei interessante seu comentário sobre XSS. Você teria artigos em português para compartilhar? Gostaria de me aprofundar no assunto. Obrigado.

Comment: Normalmente eu aponto as pessoas pra [esse artigo](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_%28Cross_Site_Scripting%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet). Ele é o mais completo que conheço na internet mas está em inglês... Quanto ao meu comentário, o problema é similar à injeção de SQL. Se você fizer `var x = "<%=y%>"`, um valor de y contendo aspas como `oi";boom();"` vai permitir que o usuário injete código JS na sua página.

Answer (score 0):

Caso esteja fazendo em javascript para você chamar a variável no ASP deverá fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
'Bloco ASP    
Dim ASP
ASP = 1

'Bloco Javascript
<script>
   var JS;
   JS = 2;
'<%=ASP%>' = JS;    
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente passar o valor da variavel JS por InnerHtml para um campo hidden e depois recupere no ASP por Request.

Veja um exemplo de como seria:

```
'Mandando o valor da variavel por JS:
document.getElementById("variavel").innerHTML = "Valor da Variavel JS";

'Campo que receberá o valor do JS.
<input type="hidden" id=variavel name=variavel>
```