# Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Estou a tentar fazer algo deste género:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function guardar_alteracoes(){ 
        <?php
            $nome = ?>$('#nome').val();<?php;
        ?>
    }

</script>
```

Ou seja, quero dar o valor a uma variável php de uma caixa de texto por javascript. O valor da caixa de texto chega bem aqui, mas não estou a conseguir igualar.

Comment: Cara, não é possível executar código PHP dentro de código Javascript, primeiro porque nem compila, segundo, por que o javascript executa somente no browser, e PHP somente no servidor, para você criar uma comunicação entre o browser e o servidor é necessário primeiro, estabelecer uma comunicação via HttpXmlRequest ou Ajax através de um `POST`

Comment: Já que está usando jquery, use ajax para enviar/receber valores do php.

Comment: ok, pensava que poderia ser possível. obrigado na mesma!

Comment: Achei o tutorial abaixo, só não testei pra ver se funciona. http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/passar-variavel-javascript-para-php

Answer (score 20, accepted):

PHP e JavaScript funcionam em momentos diferentes. O PHP gera a página e a partir daí só existe HTML e JavaScript. Assim não é possível igualar variàveis que pertencem a mundos diferentes: PHP do lado do servidor e JavaScript do lado do cliente.

Existem porém duas maneiras para poder comunicar "entre mundos". Uma delas, demasiado defenitiva para o seu caso, é fazer um formulário e passar a informação com o refresh da página.

A alternativa que procura aqui é AJAX. Uma ligação/chamada ao lado do servidor onde pode passar dados e receber passados alguns milisegundos. Um exemplo seria assim:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "seuFicheiro.php",
    data: {nomeVariavel: 'valor variável',
    success: function (data) {
        // aqui pode usar o que o PHP retorna
    }
});
```

e no lado do PHP algo como:

```
$nome = $_POST['nomeVariavel'];
// correr outro código que precise...
echo $resposta;
```

Este `echo` é o que é passado para a função success do AJAX do lado do cliente.
Espero que ajude a compreender o mecanismo.

Answer (score 0):

Isto Não é possível.
Você poderia fazer o javascript requisitar um AJAX que gravaria o valor na sessão, e na próxima execução você teria este valor.

*Alerta de gambiarra!*

Comment: ok, pensava que poderia ser possível. obrigado na mesma!

Answer (score 0):

Usando Javascript *inline* você pode fazer algo assim:

```php
<script>
  var variavelJavascript = "<?php echo variavelPHP ?>";
</script>
```

Mas lembre que, dependendo das suas necessidades, usar AJAX é o mais apropriado, como foi dito nas outras respostas.

[Veja esta pergunta feita no Stack-EN](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23740548/3153542)

---

### Atualização

Agora percebi que você quer fazer o contrário, passar uma variável JS para PHP. Neste caso só com AJAX ou *submit* de um *form* mesmo.

Comment: O contexto pede o contrário...

Comment: @DanielOmine Agora que percebi, atualizei a resposta, valeu o aviso. =)