# Funciona PHP dentro de JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

```
<script language='Javascript'>
        function confirmacaoSair() { 
            var resposta = confirm('".$_SESSION['nome'].", tem que certeza que quer sair?');
            if (resposta == true) {
                unset({$_SESSION['nome']});
                unset({$_SESSION['matricula']});
                {session_destroy()};
                window.location.href = 'index.php';
            } 
        } 
</script>
```

Desta maneira não está funcionando, mas minha dúvida é saber se funciona o que estou querendo fazer.

Comment: Possivel duplicata: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25136/129

Comment: JavaScript roda no navegador enquanto código PHP roda no servidor. O que você pode tentar fazer é criar código JavaScript enquanto a página está sendo criada pelo PHP. Eu já fiz isso em Java (JSF). Deve dar pra fazer em PHP também. Veja na minha resposta um exemplo que copiei do SO em inglês. cc @Sergio

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Não, o que você está tentando fazer não funciona.

O motivo é que o PHP é processado no servidor antes da página ser gerada. Depois que o PHP termina o seu processamento, ele é enviado ao navegador do cliente, e lá que ocorre o processamento do javascript.

O que você está tentando fazer necessitaria que o PHP ocorresse depois do javascript na mesma requisição, e isso não é possível.

A melhor solução para o seu problema é redirecionar a página no javascript (mudar o `window.location`) para uma página que desloga o usuário. No servidor, o PHP responde a página que desloga efetuando o `unset` e redirecionando para `index.php`.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript roda no navegador enquanto código PHP roda no servidor. O que você pode tentar fazer é criar código JavaScript enquanto a página está sendo criada pelo PHP.

Uma opção é imprimir os valores da variável PHP no seu código JavaScript no momento em que a página é criada pelo PHP. Exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var MyJSStringVar = "<?php Print($MyPHPStringVar); ?>";
    var MyJSNumVar = <?php Print($MyPHPNumVar); ?>;
</script>
```

Fonte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/415885/1274092