# Dificuldade ao combinar as linguagens web

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

Sou iniciante na programação web e estou fazendo confusão na hora de misturar os códigos, eu tenho estudado bastante mas ainda tenho muita dúvida no momento de combinar todos os códigos, por enquanto eu utilizo HTML, PHP, CSS, JavaScript, Jquery, Bootstrap e Ajax, vamos lá:

1- Quando vou fazer um projeto como eu posso saber que linguagem(s) usar?

2- O quê uma linguagem faz que a outra não faz?

3- Qual linguagem é melhor para cada situação?

4- Qual é a ordem em que eu devo declara-las?

5- O que dispara cada uma delas? O que é preciso para que cada uma delas seja iniciada? Todas iniciam junto? Iniciam separadas? Qual delas inicia primeiro? Qual é a melhor ordem para coloca-las? Ou depende da forma com que se programa?

6- Como saber em que momento usar cada uma delas? (Podem dar exemplos? Esta é muito importante para mim).

Quanto mais exemplos darem, melhor vai ser e tenho certeza que isto é a dúvida de muita gente.

Muito obrigado amigos!

Comment: A pergunta é ampla e pede opiniões. Não pergunta um monte de coisa junto. Leia o [tour] e a [help] para entender melhor quais tipos de perguntas são aceitáveis.

Comment: As tuas dúvidas sõ bem razoáveis mas juntando todas numa pergunta só fica dificil de responder. Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25215/129 e aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35547/129

Answer (score 5):

1. Quando vou fazer um projeto como eu posso saber que linguagem(s) usar?

Seu navegador so entende HMTL, CSS e JavaScript, linguagens como Ruby, PHP, Python, etc., irão gerar código que os navegadores entendem.

2. O quê uma linguagem faz que a outra não faz?

Difícil comparar as linguagens de backend, praticamente hoje, todas as linguagens de backend conseguem fazer a mesma coisa, a diferença é que em algumas uma tarefa pode ser mais fácil e em outras mais dificil.

3. Qual linguagem é melhor para cada situação?

Se você for trabalhar com alta performance no backend procure linguagens como Scala, Java, Erlang. Se for desenvolver projetos que você precisa desenvolver rapidamente utilize PHP, Ruby.

4. Qual é a ordem em que eu devo declara-las?

Comece pelo HTML, ele será a estrutura do seu projeto (imagine um edifício, primeiro se constrói a estrutura. Depois estilize seu HTML com CSS (acabamento). Adicione comportamento com JavaScript, efeitos, transições, callbacks, etc... Por ultimo crie comunicação com o banco de dados atravez de linguagens como PHP, Ruby, Python, etc...

5. O que dispara cada uma delas? O que é preciso para que cada uma delas seja iniciada? Todas iniciam junto? Iniciam separadas? Qual delas inicia primeiro? Qual é a melhor ordem para coloca-las? Ou depende da forma com que se programa?

Quando um usuário abre um navegador e digita uma URL, o servidor recebe essa informação (provavelmente na porta 80, http) e inicializa o servidor HTTP (apache, nginx, etc), este servidor se comunica com a aplicação e tenta resolve-la retornando uma resposta. Existe um ciclo de vida para cada requisição, podendo ser complexo ou não.

6. Como saber em que momento usar cada uma delas? (Podem dar exemplos? Esta é muito importante para mim).

Está talvez seja a pergunta mais difícil, isso depende muito do objetivo do seu projeto. Comece pelo básico, e evolua seu projeto de acordo com a necessidade.

Espero ter ajudado, as perguntas são bem genéricas e difíceis de responder.