# Capturar valor do campo pela sua ID e transformar em uma variavel

Tags: php, javascript, variáveis

Quero pegar o valor de um campo de minha tabela e transformar ele em uma variável.

Exemplo:

```
<td id='exemplo'>VALOR EXEMPLO</td>
```

quero pegar o conteúdo e transformá-lo em uma variável usando javascript, acredito q seja fácil mas n entendo muito de programação

tentei assim mas nao consegui:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var teste = $("#exemplo").val()
</script>
```

e para chamar ela no php:

```
<?php

$variavelphp = "<script>document.write(teste)</script>";

echo "$variavelphp"
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mude sua linha de código `js` para o seguinte:

```
var teste = $("#exemplo").html();
```

Ficaria assim:

```js
var teste = $("#exemplo").html();
alert(teste);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td id='exemplo'>VALOR EXEMPLO 1</td>
    <td id='exemplo1'>VALOR 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Primeiramente, a chamada do evento do `JQuery` `$("#exemplo").val()` se refere ao atributo `value` de algum elemento, onde normalmente ficam guardados os valores dos elementos, porém o seu elemento em questão na verdade é um `td`(estrutura do corpo de uma tabela) que além de tudo, também não possui um atributo `value` nativo, para pegar seu valor, o certo semanticamente seria colocar um outro elemento dentro dele, por exemplo um `span` ou um `label`, que ficaria mais ou menos assim: `<td><label id='exemplo' value='VALOR EXEMPLO 1'>VALOR EXEMPLO 1</label></td>`, desse modo sua linha de comando `JQuery` nem precisaria ser alterada. Mas isso vai de acordo com cada um...

Estruturando da forma como você deseja, o elemento `td` apenas "escreve" na tela o que esta contido nele, ou seja o tipo de elemento `td` não possui nativamente o atributo `value`.
Para pegar o conteúdo/valor contido dentro de um `td`, você devera usar o evento `JavaScript` `innerHTML();` que em `JQuery` equivale ao evento `HTML();`

Comment: funcionou perfeitamente para o que eu queria, muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Se quer pegar o conteúdo de um elemento em JS, basta isso:

```
var teste = document.getElementById('exemplo').innerText;
```

Mas vale dizer que não vai funcionar com um `td` avulso, sem a estrutura da tabela.

Veja um exemplo funcional:

```js
var teste = document.getElementById('exemplo').innerText;

//So para demonstrar:
document.body.innerHTML += 'O valor é ' + teste;
```

```html
<div id="exemplo">VALOR EXEMPLO</div>
```

Neste caso usei uma `div` para evitar o problema mencionado com o `td` avulso.

Foi usado o `innerText`, que é preferível para pegar o conteúdo textual. Se quiser pegar algo que contenha elementos filhos, dê preferência ao `innerHTML`.

Se sua dúvida é sobre variáveis de PHP, aí o assunto muda, e vale a pena uma lida nisso:

> [Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/)

Comment: Creio o que ele se expressou mal, fica claro ao ver o último bloco de código. Sendo assim, sua reposta não esta correta, pois ele mesmo resolveu o problema de pegar o valor de um elemento e botar em uma variável, só que em JavaScript.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, li a pergunta sobre igualar varial php a uma do javascript e me ajudou por terei que fazer isso.

Comment: @user5978 eu respondi a parte que não era duplicata, pois ficou claro que o autor não tem muita experiência com esta parte de integração. A parte do PHP eu pus o link pra resposta que tem o que ele procura, pois não vai ajudar ninguém eu colocar conteúdo repetido no site. Se você olhar o histórico de edições, vai ver que na verdade eu tinha até fechado como duplicata, mas preferi cobrir todas as condições possíveis para ajudar o autor, portanto reabri e respondi com o que faltava:  http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/125296/revisions

Comment: @user5978 agora, se apontar onde é que minha resposta está errada, aí podemos ver o que fazer. Reli tudo, e não fez muito sentido esse seu comentário. Se puder ser mais específico em qual parte não está correta, ajudaria. Afinal, mostrei como fazer em JS (que ele vai precisar de qualquer forma, mesmo passando pra PHP), e apontei pra como fazer em PHP. Faltou o que?

Comment: O cara diz que precisa pegar uma variável em JavaScript, e deve passar ela para o PHP. E ele afirma que tentou de determinado jeito (mostra que pegou corretamente o valor com o JavaScript), mas que porém não conseguiu fazer este valor chegar ao PHP.

Comment: Mostrar outra forma de fazer o que ele já fez, sem ao menos dar uma dica do trecho que ele realmente precisa, não é uma solução para a problema. Na minha humilde opinião.

Comment: @user5978 Então sua sugestão é em vez de colocar o link, reproduzir a outra resposta aqui? Isso eu não vou fazer. O que eu percebi é que a outra resposta que faz o mesmo que a minha, mas precisa de jQuery, você não comentou nada, então isso esclarece outras coisas também. De qualquer forma, grato pelo retorno.

Comment: Geralmente eu utilizo comentários para apontar soluções externas, quando não tenho nada a acrescentar (A respeito do conteúdo do link).

Comment: Verdade, bati o olho naquela resposta, e podia jurar que o cara tinha sugerido a utilização de ajax ... eu ia comentar lá ... mas chega de treta por hoje :D

Comment: @user5978 nao tem treta, fique sossegado que pra mim é numa boa. Você apontou algo, e eu quis entender melhor. Só isso. Respeito 100% sua opinião, independente de concordar ou não, e acho muito bom que você a expresse. E fique à vontade pra criticar sempre que achar necessário.