# Retornar valores de php com javascript

Tags: php, javascript

Eu em java fiz um projeto que em várias partes do programa chamava uma função para ir à base de dados buscar um valor e retornar, do tipo `String nome = acessocliente.obtemnome(id);` onde na classe acessocliente eu tinha um parametro chamado obtemnome que devolvia o nome do cliente pelo id. 
Bom eu queria fazer isso em JavaScript e PHP. 
Ou seja algures no código JavaScript chamar o php do tipo `var nome = "obtemnome.php?id="+id;`

Como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: É sufeciente teres a variável quando a página carrega ou vais buscar à BD depois da página ter carregado?

Comment: Depois da página já ter carregado.

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25215/129, acho que é isso que precisas, eventualmente com JS nativo.

Comment: Como eu depois posso passar o resultado para variável naquele código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poderia fazer assim:

```
$("#div_qualquer").load("obtemnome.php",{id:id}, function(response){
   alert(response); //alerta a resposta obtida do PHP
});
```

A única alteração que fiz no seu código, foi passar os parâmetros via `POST` para o PHP, no entanto, se preferir passar via `GET` mesmo, basta revover isto `{id:id}`;