# FullCalendar: chmar um arquivo externo Json

Tags: javascript, json

Boa tarde,
estou tentando carregar um evento no FullCalendar. O problema é o seguinte

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
                left: 'today',
                center: 'prev, title, next',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
                        eventClick:  function(event) {
                             $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                             $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                             $('#eventUrl').attr('href',event.url);
                             $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                             return false;
                        },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                events:[
                    <?php include('process.php') ?>
               ]
      });
});
```

Process.PHP

```
<?php
    $title = "Jose";
    $start = "2016-11-01";

echo "{
       title: '$title' ,
       start: '$start' 
       }";
?>
```

Dessa maneira eu consigo carregar, porém gostaria de saber como eu faço chamando um JSON? tentei de diversas formas ($.getJson, $.get, Json.parser(), etc...) Alguem tem alguma dica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu uso o 'events' do próprio fullcalendar, segue o código:

```js
events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {

   //chama o ajax e retorna um  result/promise com os dados 'data'
    var events = []; //create array to events
  $.each(data, function(index, val) { //passa por cada resultado do array
   events.push({       //adiciona os dados no array 'events'
    title: val.title,
    start: val.start,
   })
  });
  callback(events); //callback que irá preencher o calendário, com o array de eventos.
 }
},
```

Ele irá carregar todos os eventos retornados do ajax, no calendário, qualquer dúvida, só entrar em contato.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, mas minha dúvida é como chamar um arquivo JSON, pois carregar eu até consigo

Comment: Depois de 2 dias se debatendo, a tua resposta foi a que resolveu meu problema. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar ajax para ir buscar esse JSON e quando o ajax completar correr o código que tens. Algo assim:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.getJSON("/Process.PHP", function(event) {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'today',
                center: 'prev, title, next',
                right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
            },
            eventClick: function(event) {
                $('#modalTitle').html(event.title);
                $('#modalBody').html(event.description);
                $('#eventUrl').attr('href', event.url);
                $('#fullCalModal').modal();
                return false;
            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            editable: true,
            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: [event]
        });
    });
});
```

Eventualmente quererás passar uma array e não somente um objeto de cada vez. Nesse caso no JavaScript podes ter `events: events` e no PHP fazer `echo` de uma array. Lembra-te que podes usar o [`json_encode` do PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) para gerar JSON.

Comment: Eu não conheço o AJAX, tem algum site que possa me indicar?
encontrei o codigo
$.ajax({
    url: endereco,
    complete: function(res){
        var meuJSON = JSON.parse(res.responseText);
        console.log(meuJSON); 
    }
});
mas preciso de exemplo para me basear

Comment: @JoseLeandro esse código que colocaste no comentário é uma maneira mais longa de fazer o que eu coloquei na resposta. Dá uma olhada aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/25215/129, mas no fundo é o que coloquei na resposta usando a versão específica e simplificada do jQuery para AJAX + JSON, que é o `getJSON`. Testaste o meu código?

Comment: @JoseLeandro também interessante: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/116177/129

Comment: Meu condigo do Json é
{
    "eventos":[
        {
            "title":"Jose",
            "start":"2016-09-01"
        }
    ]
}
eu deveria modificar algo?

Comment: @JoseLeandro já tens esse json no javascript com o getJSON?

Comment: Meu código esta assim:
index.php
$.getJSON("eventos.json", function(event){
...
events:[ event ]
}
e meu Json
eventos.json
{
    "eventos":[
        {
            "title":"Jose",
            "start":"2016-09-01"
        }
    ]
}
estou dando uma pesquisada na maneira que retorna

Comment: Coloca no JSON somente a array, sem o "{eventos:}"

Comment: So close,
coloquei como tu disse, e coloquei o
events: alert(event)
E a resposta que tenho é
[object Object]
novamente comecei minha busca pelo conhecimento e a única resposta que encontro é que não precisa do JSON.parse, porém o erro acontece se eu não utiliza-lo e utilizando-o está ocorrendo SyntaxError JSON.parse, sendo que meu código esta assim:
var ObjEventos = JSON.parse(event);
e meu eventos.Json está assim:
[
        {
            "title":"Jose",
            "start":"2016-09-01"
        }
    ]

Comment: O erro é: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Comment: @JoseLeandro no PHP coloca assim: `echo '[{"title":"Jose", "start":"2016-09-01"}]';` e no JavaScript assim: http://jsfiddle.net/hge7Lxza/

Comment: Dessa maneira funciona, porém dessa maneira tenho que utilizar um arquivo php, sabe se teria como eu fazer a mesma coisa só que com um arquivo .Json?

Comment: @JoseLeandro da mesma maneira... http://jsfiddle.net/hge7Lxza/1/ e no ficheiro `.json` somente `[{"title":"Jose", "start":"2016-09-01"}]` sem aspas antes ou depois.

Comment: Bom dia, testei, porém ele retorna [object Object]. Eu fiz um teste apenas com  $.get e ele esta me retornando [ { "title":"Jose", "start":"2016-11-01" }
] que é o que preciso que retorne para o events: do full calendário possa ler, mas o "events:" do full calendário não lê, tu saberia me dizer o por quê?
Principal.php
$.get("eventos.json", function(varEventos){
   events: varEventos
}
eventos.json
[
    {
        "title":"Jose",
        "start":"2016-11-01"
    }
]