# Passar variável inteira de javascript para php

Tags: php, javascript

Gostaria de saber por que o seguinte trecho não funciona...

```
<?php
$window = '<script>document.write(window.innerWidth)</script>';

//exemplo de saída `string(50) "1366"`

if($window > 920) {
    echo 'maior';
}else{
    echo 'menor';
}
?>
```

Mesmo usando métodos como `intval` e `(int)` no `PHP` e `parseInt` no `javascript` ele não faz a verificação correta, ao tentar transformar em inteiro ele retorna 0, qual a explicação?

Comment: `$window` não seria um `HTML Collect`?

Comment: Porque não faz sentido o que você fez. Pesquise sobre as diferenças de *server-side* e *client-side* para entender quando o PHP e o JavaScript são executados. O único meio deles se comunicarem é através de requisições HTTP.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no seguinte link https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%C3%A1vel-php-a-uma-vari%C3%A1vel-javascript

Comment: "*esse método é totalmente possível*", não, não é. Desta maneira, sua variável PHP sempre será uma *string* com o código JS. Só irá gerar um valor inteiro quando esse código for analisado pelo navegador, mas o PHP já não estará mais presente.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss , a variável php recebe o valor correto, ou seja no exemplo ela recebe "1366" que é a resolução da minha tela em pixels, não o código, porém ele sempre armazena como string, e a mesmo não pode ser tratada como inteiro, gostaria de saber o por que disso, se quizer testar o código vai ver do que estou falando.

Comment: Se ela recebe o valor correto, deve haver mais código além do que você apresentou. Da maneira que está, o código JS não será executado pelo PHP.

Comment: http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/passar-variavel-javascript-para-php um exemplo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Comunicação entre JavaScript e PHP

Tentei nos comentários, mas vi que iria se estender demais e resolvi responder. O código que você fez não funciona porque **não faz sentido**. A **única forma** de comunicação entre JavaScript, que executa no lado do cliente, com o PHP, que executa do lado do servidor, são **mensagens HTTP**, tanto a requisição quanto a resposta. Considerando o código apresentado:

```
<?php
$window = '<script>document.write(window.innerWidth)</script>';

//exemplo de saída `string(50) "1366"`

if($window > 920) {
    echo 'maior';
}else{
    echo 'menor';
}
?>
```

Primeiro, você atribui uma *string* à variável `$window`. O conteúdo é um código JavaScript, mas isso não faz diferença para o PHP; **ele irá tratá-la como uma *string* qualquer e este código JS não será analisado**, pois quem faria isso é o navegador, no lado do cliente, mas ainda estamos executando no lado do servidor. Quando você faz a comparação, você está **comparando uma *string* com um *int***. Isso não dá erro porque é PHP e ele te permite fazer coisas sem sentido. Você comentou que tentou converter para *int* e sempre obtém zero; isso está explicado na [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion) do PHP:

> Quando uma string é interpretada como um valor numérico, o valor
>   resultante e seu tipo é determinado como segue.
>
> Se a string não conter nenhum dos caracteres '.', 'e', ou 'E' e o
>   valor numérico encaixa-se dentro dos limites do tipo inteiro (definido
>   pela constante PHP_INT_MAX), a string será avaliada como um inteiro.
>   Em todos os outros casos será interpretada como um float.
>
> O valor é obtido da porção inicial da string. Se a string começar com
>   dados numéricos válidos, esse será o valor utilizado. **Caso contrário,
>   o valor será 0 (zero)**. Dados numéricos válidos são um sinal opcional,
>   seguido de um ou mais dígitos (opcionalmente contendo um ponto
>   decimal), seguido de um expoente, também opcional. O expoente é um 'e'
>   ou 'E' seguido de um ou mais dígitos.

Como sua ***string* não é um valor numérico válido, o PHP sempre retornará 0**. A única forma, atente-se ao **única**, é enviar este valor via requisição HTTP, podendo ser síncrona ou assíncrona, dependendo do que pretende fazer.

Com jQuery, por exemplo, você poderia fazer algo como:

```
$.post("window.php", {width: window.innerWidth}).done(data => {
    alert(data);
});
```

E no PHP, fazer a verificação tratando a requisição assíncrona feito pelo JavaScript acima:

```
<?php

$width = $_POST["width"];

if ($width > 920) {
     echo "maior";
} else {
     echo "menor";
}
```

---

## Por que apareceu `string(50) "1366"`?

Acredito que foi aqui que gerou toda a confusão, pois ao executar o `var_dump` da variável, constou um valor numérico e não a *string*. Isso ocorreu porquê a saída da função `var_dump` foi enviada ao navegador via resposta HTTP e a saída desta função é:

```
string(50) "<script>document.write(window.innerWidth)</script>"
```

O navegador recebeu esse valor e o reproduziu na tela. Porém, como o conteúdo da *string* é um código JavaScript, o navegador entenderá que ele deve ser analisado, pois o mesmo está entre as *tags* `script`. Ou seja, ao exibir o valor na tela, será renderizado um valor numérico referente ao valor de `window.innerWidth`, mas isso não significa que este valor existe no PHP, pois não existe. Ele só é gerado quando o código é renderizado pelo navegador. Prova disso, basta você acessar o código fonte do resultado e verá que, na verdade, o que chegou ao navegador foi a *string* original e não o valor numérico.

---

## Mas neste link diz que se faz assim...

Você citou um [link](http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/passar-variavel-javascript-para-php) em que aparentemente se baseou para fazer seu código. O que o site apresenta nada tem a ver com passar o valor de uma variável JavaScript para PHP. O que **ele fez foi apenas gerar código JS através do PHP**, mas não existe nenhuma relação entre eles. Por exemplo, considerando o código apresentado na página:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Passar Variável Javascript para PHP</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var variaveljs = 'Mauricio Programador'; 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
 <?php 
  $variavelphp = "<script>document.write(variaveljs)</script>";
  echo "Olá $variavelphp";
 ?>
</body>
</html>
```

O que é feito é que o PHP irá tratar a requisição para este arquivo e, ao analisar o PHP, gerará o seguinte resultado:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Passar Variável Javascript para PHP</title>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var variaveljs = 'Mauricio Programador'; 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
  Olá <script>document.write(variaveljs)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Esse conteúdo será enviado ao navegador via resposta HTTP e será analisado pelo mesmo, exibindo o nome na tela, porém em nenhum momento a variável JS estava disponível no PHP. Tudo indica que o autor deste site não tem domínio do protocolo utilizado em páginas web e parece ser uma péssima referência a seguir.

Comment: Agradeço a resposta, tenho um grande domínio em server e client side, porém isso foi uma dúvida que me surgiu em testes sem compromisso, e nesse teste em especifico o PHP realmente pegou o valor da variável, porém com a seguinte notação no var_dump string(50) "1366", ou seja sem sentido nenhum, nessa maquina estou usando a versão 5.6, basta tu fazer um teste simples, que irá obter o mesmo resultado

Comment: @FelipeDuarte no momento que disse sobre a falta de domínio era referente ao autor do site que você citou, pois o material é de péssima qualidade. Espero que tenha ficado claro a resposta e suprido suas dúvidas. Se não, sinta-se a vontade para questionar o que ainda não ficou claro.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte, sim, acho que agora compreendi o que aconteceu. Irei completar a resposta com a explicação. De fato, acaba sendo algo propício a confusão.

Comment: @FelipeDuarte editei a resposta, adicionando a explicação do `string(50) "1366"`. Veja se ficou suficientemente claro.

Comment: Agora ficou totalmente claro, não imaginava que a saída era processada dessa forma, isso causa muita confusão, agradeço a resposta.

Answer (score 0):

PHP é uma linguagem *server side.* Isso significa: roda no servidor.
Javascript é uma linguagem *client side*. Ou seja: roda na interface do browser.

Dito isso, é importante responder que o PHP, ao rodar no servidor, tem conhecimento zero sobre como ele será usado. Ele é executado e seu resultado pode ser consumido por alguma outra origem: browser (através de requisições ajax ou acesso direto), linha de comando, entre outros.

Assim, `window.innerWidth` nada significa para o servidor. Não é, assim, possível realizar rotinas javascript através do PHP (ao menos, não dessa forma).

Comment: http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/passar-variavel-javascript-para-php

Comment: O @anderson já sanou essa sua dúvida