# Como pegar variável script e inserir num banco php?

Tags: php, javascript, html, sql, select

Tenho um campo select conforme o código abaixo:

```
<select id="teste">
    <option>oie</option>
    <option>tchau</option>
```

Tenho um botao para executar um insert no banco de dados através da chamada de funcao onclick:

```
<input type="button" value="ok" onclick="teste()">
```

E uma function Java Script para obter o valor do select :

```
<script >

  jQuery("#teste").change(function(){
    var setor = jQuery(this).val();// pega o valor escolhido no select 
    var oi = setor;
    alert(oi);

  })

  function teste(){
    <?php
      $serverName = "servidor"; 
      $connectioninfo = array( "Database"=>"banco", "UID"=>"usuario", "PWD"=>"senha");
      $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectioninfo);
      $conteudo = "<script>document.write(setor)</script>";
      $oi =  " $conteudo";
      $query ="insert into teste(setor) values('$oi')";
      $output=sqlsrv_query($conn,$query) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));       
   ?>
}

</script>
```

No entanto o valor inserido no banco de dados está ficando assim : 
"document.write(setor)"
O que está errado?

O objetivo nao é usar form action vou utilizar ajax para fazer minha consulta em tempo real mas primeiro queria entender como jogar a variavel javascript dentro de value no meu insert PHP

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss nao é duplicata, sei fazer a conexao php e inserir no banco de dados no entanto a informação que esta indo pra lá(variavel javascript) esta indo de forma incorreta, na forma literal "<script>nomedavariavel</script>"

Comment: Exatamente. Da forma que fez não faz sentido algum e é um indício que você não domina os conceitos básicos para fazer a operação. Eu abordei todos (ou quase todos) na minha outra resposta, por isso sinalizei como duplicada. Se você ler a minha resposta, verá que possui 3 partes. Você aparentemente sabe a parte 3, mas recomendo fortemente ler e estudar os conceitos das partes 1 e 2.

Comment: Acredito que vc nao tenha entendido minha pergunta @AndersonCarlosWoss...

Comment: Entendi perfeitamente. Você está tentando rodar um *script* PHP dentro de uma função JS. Isso não faz sentido, pois PHP roda no lado do servidor, enquanto JS roda no lado do cliente. A única comunicação entre eles é uma mensagem HTTP. Acredito que são esses os conceitos que lhe faltam para resolver o problema e estão todos descritos na outra resposta. Por isso julgo ser duplicada.

Comment: Com a sua edição dizendo que irá utilizar AJAX muda um pouco a situação. A requisição AJAX gerará a mensagem HTTP que você precisa para comunicar entre JS e PHP. Tente fazer isso diretamente já, pois o código que tem hoje, que postou na pergunta, não faz sentido pelos motivos descritos no comentário anterior. Já adianto que no site também há inúmeras perguntas sobre AJAX e PHP, então provavelmente será duplicada de alguma outra.

Comment: Por exemplo: [Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/25136/5878)