# Passar variável JS para PHP

Tags: php, javascript

Boa noite, Estou tentando exibir apenas vendedores de uma loja especifica. Essa loja ja aparece automaticamente quando e digitado o numero de cupom. Mas para exibir o vendedor, preciso de uma consulta comparando com a variavel da consulta da loja que esta dentro do JS, como faco para pegar essa variavel e usar ela na comparacao para trazer a lista de vendedores daquela loja? Alguem pode me ajudar com isso

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input[name='comprovante']").blur(function() {
            var $loja = $("input[name='loja']");
            var $idloja = $("input[name='idloja']");
            $.getJSON('../function2.php', {
                comprovante: $(this).val()
            }, function(json) {
                $loja.val(json.lnome);
                $idloja.val(json.idloja);
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Igualar variável php a uma variável javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25136/igualar-vari%c3%a1vel-php-a-uma-vari%c3%a1vel-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

no seu aquivo function2.php você deve fazer algo parecido com isso

```
$comprovante  = $_GET['comprovante'];

// exemplo caso só precise percorrer uma lista

foreach ($lista_vendedores as $vendedor) {
   if($comprovante ==  $vendedor->loja){
     // realiza operação
   }

}

// exemplo de uma query caso fosse guscar em um banco
$query = "SELECT * FROM vendedo WHERE comprovante = $comprovante ";

// como retorna 
// informa que os dados retornados serão json
header('Content-type: application/json');

$array = array("lnome" => "nome do vendedor", "idloja" => "id da loja");


// retorna os dador
echo json_encode($array);
```